# how to replace splash screen with drawer screen in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to have a splash screen and a home screen that contains drawer.
I'm facing some issue here.
The below is my stack navigator.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import SplashScreen from '../Screens/SplashScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```

The splashScreen

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [splashScreen, setSplashScreen] = useState(true);
  const hideSplashScreen = () => {
    setSplashScreen(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setTimeout(() => {
      hideSplashScreen();
      navigation.replace('Home');
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  const renderSplash = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 100}}>
        <Text>Welcome</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return <View>{splashScreen === true && renderSplash()}</View>;
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

DrawerNavigator

```
import React from 'react';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you're using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
]);

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

HomeScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default HomeScreen;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import StackNavigator from './navigation/StackNavigator';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
Icon.loadFont().then();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

On the homeScreen header of Stack navigation is shown up with title Home. Below that header of drawer Navigation is showing up.
I just want to see drawer on the home screen. How to achieve this? Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need to show a splash screen when the user enters the app.

### What's wrong in it?

Splash screen should be shown when your app bundle & assets are loading. If you are mounting your splash screen inside the App component, the splash screen will be showing after the bundle and asset loading.

### Recommended

Try to use [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen) library.

Follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9)